# Construct a regular pentagon in only 11 steps using ruler and compass.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

One step is to draw a stright line or a circle (greek classical understsnding of step)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. What is your question? Please explain what you're having trouble with, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: My question is how to construct such a pentagon using straightedge and compass as the ancient greek style.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing coherent

Comment: This seems a way too specific question.

Answer (score 4):

From [the Pentagon article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon):

[image]