# How to draw a regular pentagon with compass and straightedge

Tags: geometry, polygons, geometric-construction

I remember reading that Gauss managed to construct a regular pentagon with just a compass and straightedge, but I don't remember the particulars of how he did this. Could someone help me out and give me instructions on how to do this?

Comment: Euclid did too, *much* earlier. Do you want Gauss's construction, or any? And have you tried looking around the web, for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon)?

Comment: @pjs36 ANY construction, but Gauss's would be great.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281221/construct-a-regular-pentagon-in-only-11-steps-using-ruler-and-compass/1281273#1281273

Comment: The 19 year old Gauss showed how to construct [a regular 17-sided polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagon), and later characterized [which regular polygons are constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon).

Answer (score 9):

I think this is the easiest way to draw a regular pentagon with just a compass and straightedge.
[image]

Comment: this is not a regular pentagon

Answer (score 2):

I only know two constructions. The first I learned in high school and involves straightedge and compass:
[image]

The other I learned in college as I studied compass-only (Mohr-Mascheroni) constructions.  Ironically the compass-only construction is one of the simplest constructions Ive seen, only requiring 10 circles, the line-segments at the end are cosmetic.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this one is Gauss', but here's the one I use:

1. Draw a circle. Let the center be $O$.
2. Define a direction as "left" and draw a line from the center going "left" until you hit the circle. This segment is $OA$.
3. Draw another line segment, this time going "up" (this is perfectly legal - you should know how to construct a perpendicular line to a segment). This segment is $OB$.
4. Find the midpoint of $OA$, calling it $M$.
5. Draw $BM$.
6. Find the angle bisector of $BMO$ and draw until you hit $OB$. Call this intersection $I$.
7. Draw a perpendicular line to $OB$ going "left" until you hit the circle at a point $C$. $BC$ is now one line segment of the pentagon and the rest is relatively simple (just draw circle centered around $C$ passing through $B$ to get third vertex, etc.)

Something like this:

[image]